# How can I automate the installation of gems like active_storage and devise in my custom gem when used in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have created a custom gem in which I have integrated some basic gems like active storage, devise and will_paginate etc. So when normally we add active_storage gem we have to run active_storage installation command that creates its migration, some thing is happening with my gem when I used my created gem in some rails application it requires me to use that command to work properly and to create migration, Is there any way in which I can add these kind of commands in script which I want developer to use after bundle install command, like all devise or active storage commands run at once, not need to run them one by one.

bin/my_script (with no extension)
example code which you can add 'system("rails db:migrate")'

I have tried to add some script but I dont know where to write?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your issue. You can create a command that needs to be run after adding your gem, just like the other gems do. And in the command, you call the initializing commands of the gems that you are adding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can specify gem dependencies in your own gem...

If your gem is called my_awesome_tem, then in your my_awesome_gem.gemspec file you specify development-time and run-time dependencies like this:

```rb
# my_awesome_gem.gemspec
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name = "my_awesome_gem"
  s.version = "0.1"

  s.authors = ["My Name"]
  s.description = "just does awesome things"
  s.files         = Dir['Gemfile', 'Rakefile', 'README.md','app/**/*','config/**/*','db/**/*','lib/**/*','spec/**/*']
  s.summary = "awesome gem"

  s.add_runtime_dependency("rails", ["> 7.0.0"])
  s.add_development_dependency("sqlite3-ruby")
  s.add_development_dependency("capybara")
  s.add_development_dependency("rspec-rails", [">= 2.0.0"])
  s.add_development_dependency("faker")
  s.add_development_dependency("factory_bot_rails")
  s.add_development_dependency("database_cleaner")
  s.add_runtime_dependency("haml")
end

# Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"
gemspec
```

alternatively you can include them in the Gemfile of your gem, the same way you would for a Rails app